# how do I get to a random index in a object that holds a array of objects and get a specific property and append that property content?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, random

I'm trying to make a trivia game as a project at my bootcamp I'm still new to coding but I get some basic stuff and I want to use Dom manipulation to grab a object from state that holds a questions array of objects and I'm using the form element in html to make the textContent of the label element in the form to be the question property which is a string and evaluate the input to the answer that I put in my trivia question constructor. I have tried everything i learned so far but I'm getting no where.

```
class Question {
  constructor(question, answer, hint) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
    this.hint = hint;
    this.attempts = 3;
    state.questions.push(this);
  }
}
```

```
// helper function for generating a random question from the state index.
function getRandomQuestion() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * state.questions.length);
}
```

```
function renderQuestion() {

  let currentQuestion = getRandomQuestion();
  for (let i = state.questions.length; i === 0; pocketArray.push(state.questions[currentQuestion])) {
    while (state.questions[currentQuestion].attempts > 0) {
      question.innerText = state.questions[currentQuestion].question;
    }
  }
}
```

```
     <form class="current-question">
                <label for="userInput" id="question"></label>
                <input type="text" name="userInput" id="user">
                <button type="button" for="userInput" id="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: The `for` loop doesn't do anything. The condition `i === 0` will be false when you start, so the loop ends immediately.

Comment: And the third part of a `for` header is supposed to update the iteration variable, e.g. `i--` to subtract 1 from it.

Comment: You don't need a loop at all.  All you need is the assignment. The `while` loop also makes no sense, since `attempts` never changes during the loop. So it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: First, check in the console when you create a new Question instance...
"Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined"